# SHA-1 Keys for anyone to view Application

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I'm currently working on an android app for a school project and was using Google authentication via Firebase. To use my application I generated a SHA-1 debug key from my local, however it might be unrealistic of me to ask for the teaching teams' SHA1-keys for each and every one of their computers. I've heard of a android release key, but am unsure whether to use it because my application will not be going live anytime soon. So I need a way where anyone can use Google signin on my app, is generating a release key the only thing  I can do (and does this guarantee anyone can sign in?) or is there another way?

Comment: You can copy your default debug keystore or generate an new keystore and distribute it together with your project. The keystore then can be used for each debug build. This way, the debug version of your app will always have the same signature.

Comment: How do I "distribute it together"? Even for the other members of my group I've had to get their keys and input them into firebase for them to login. Apologies I'm fairly new to android development

Comment: Would I need to give my debug.keystore to everyone so they can replace their current ones?

Comment: With "Distribute it together" I mean, put the keystore in the same GIT repository as your Android project. This way, everybody who checks out your project and builds it, uses the same signing key. People don't need to replace any of their keys. You specify *your* keystore for *your* project in its build.gradle file. Other projects won't care about the keystore.